# How to get value from json value in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json file

```
{
"value":  [
              {
                  "applicationVersion":  "@{major=14; minor=5; build=35970; revision=0; majorRevision=0; minorRevision=0}",
                  "ringName":  "PROD",
                  "ringFriendlyName":  "Production"
              },
              {
                  "applicationVersion":  "@{major=15; minor=0; build=35903; revision=0; majorRevision=0; minorRevision=0}",
                  "ringName":  "PREVIEW",
                  "ringFriendlyName":  "Preview"
              }
          ]
}
```

I want to get major, minor, build and revision values from the ringName = Preview.

I tried this

```
$supportedVersions = $myJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$appVersion = $supportedVersions.value | where { $_.ringFriendlyName -eq "Preview" } | Select -ExpandProperty "applicationVersion"
```

this returns me

```
@{major=15; minor=0; build=35903; revision=0; majorRevision=0; minorRevision=0}
```

but when I try

```
    $major = $appVersion | select major
```

it returns me nothing

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: The value of `applicationVersion` is a string `"@{major=14; ...}"`. The string doesn't have a property `major`. Either parse the value out of the string with a regular expression, or change whatever PowerShell script creates that JSON file to use a depth >2 for the JSON export (e.g. `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers actually, it appears it's an Array according to GetType on that field.

Comment: @AustinTFrench No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the field `applicationVersion` in your JSON data is a string. From the looks of it the JSON was created via `ConvertTo-Json` without specifying the conversion depth. By default `ConvertTo-Json` mangles all substructures below the 2nd level of hierarchy into strings.

The best solution to your problem would be to fix the JSON export by adding the parameter `-Depth` with a value >2 to the `ConvertTo-Json` call, e.g.

```
... | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | ...
```

If you can't do that you need to parse the desired information out of the string, e.g. with a regular expression:

```
$appVersion |
    Select-String '(?<=major=)\d+' |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```

A somewhat more creative approach involving scriptblocks might look like this:

```
$appVersion | ForEach-Object {
    (& ([Scriptblock]::Create($_))).major
}
```

Note, however, that I don't actually recommend using the latter approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried that. I'm not controlling the initial JSON - that's the output from the API. I tried first approach, it does not work for me.  The secont one works only for major parameter

Comment: @DmitryKatson Sorry, there was a typo in the first approach. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the data as it is, you can invoke the output string as a script. This will yield a hash table with properties that you can reference.

```
$appVersion = $supportedVersions.value |
    Where-Object { $_.ringFriendlyName -eq "Preview" } |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "applicationVersion") | Invoke-Expression

$appVersion.Major
15
```

As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) has pointed out, this is not going to be a preferred approach. `Invoke-Expression` is generally considered "bad" or "evil" since malicious code could easily be unknowingly executed. You must trust the source from which data is provided.

Comment: or just pipe the existing command into Invoke-Expression... ```$appVersion = $supportedVersions.value | where { $_.ringFriendlyName -eq "Preview" } | Select -ExpandProperty "applicationVersion" |Invoke-Expression```

Comment: it's worth noting this will execute the string as a powershell script with the current process privileges - make sure you trust your input, otherwise a malicious party could provide a json document with something like "applicationVersion="Format-Volume C:" and you'll do bad things

Comment: i'm not unhappy - it's a valid approach *if* you trust the input. just letting the OP know in case they don't...

Comment: I added an extra statement. Hopefully, that will be enough to warn the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill for your example, but to *safely* convert an arbitrary PowerShell expression into a value you can use the built-in PowerShell parser. The code below works for a Hashtable...

```bsh
function ConvertTo-HashTable
{
    param( [string] $PsCode )
    $tokens = $null;
    $errors = $null;
    $scriptBlockAst = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($PsCode, [ref] $tokens, [ref] $errors);
    if( $errors.Length -gt 0 )
    {
        throw "Invalid powershell script - errors are:`r`n$errors";
    }
    $hashtableAst = $scriptBlockAst.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].Expression;
    if( ($null -eq $hashtableAst) -or
        -not ($hashtableAst -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.HashTableAst]) )
    {
        throw "couldn't find a hashtable in the script";
    }
    return $hashtableAst.SafeGetValue();
}
```

Example:

```
PS> ConvertTo-Hashtable "@{`"major`" = 15}"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
major                          15
```

Note that it will throw an exception if there are any expressions in the string, thereby protecting you from PowerShell injection attacks:

```
PS> ConvertTo-Hashtable "@{`"major`" = 1 + 1}"
Exception calling "SafeGetValue" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot generate a Windows PowerShell object for a ScriptBlock
evaluating dynamic expressions. Dynamic expression: @{"major" = 1 + 1}."
At line:17 char:12
+     return $hashtableAst.SafeGetValue();
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

```
PS> ConvertTo-Hashtable "@{`"major`" = (Format-Volume -DriveLetter X)}"
Exception calling "SafeGetValue" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot generate a Windows PowerShell object for a ScriptBlock
evaluating dynamic expressions. Dynamic expression: @{"major" = (Format-Volume -DriveLetter X)}."
At line:17 char:12
+     return $hashtableAst.SafeGetValue();
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```